# How do I handle selected values in a nested association in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a `Profile` model, that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :grades`.

My `Grade` model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: grades
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  subject    :string
#  result     :string
#  grade_type :integer
#  profile_id :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  enum grade_type: { csec: 0, cape: 1, sat: 2, g7: 3, g8: 4, g9: 5, g10: 6, g11: 7, g12: 8, g13: 9 }
end
```

In my `profiles/_form.html.erb`, I have the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :grades, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |g| %>
    <%= g.input_field :grade_type, collection: Grade.grade_types.keys, include_blank: false, class: 'col-lg-8 form-control' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, that shows me the `grade_types` from the enum values like I would expect.

But what I want to happen is, when I am editing a record, and it shows the grades, it should have the grade_type pre-selected.

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you whitelisting the `grade_types` param in your controller? `require(:profile).permit(grades_attributes: [:grade_type])`

Comment: @max Yes. That's not the issue. The issue is detecting what has been selected and identifying it.

Comment: Hmm try `collection: User.statuses.map {|k,v| [k, k] }` - SimpleForm delegates down `ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper` and it may be having issues linking `g.object.grade_type` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

Get the grade_type from the grade object `g.object` and pass it to the input field via selected:

```
<%= f.input_field :grade_type, collection: Grade.grade_types.keys, selected: g.object.grade_type, include_blank: false, class: 'col-lg-8 form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`simple_form` has a nifty option to preselect a value. You could either use the `:selected` option for this as such:

```
<%= f.input_field :grade_type, collection: Grade.grade_types.keys, include_blank: false, class: 'col-lg-8 form-control', selected: @grade[:grade_type] %>
```

I'm not really sure of doing the same for nested attributes though, but sure seems like something I'd love to learn

Comment: Yeh I know about `:selected`. But what I am really struggling with is both the nested attributes part, along with the enum value of said nested attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The [enum_help](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help) gem lets you do this:

```
<%= f.input :grade_type %>
```